# For each Hausdorff space, a completely regular quotient space. Problem from Dugundji's Topology [mistake on the problem].

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, separation-axioms

I got stuck on problem 1, section 7, Chapter VII (Separation Axioms) of Dugundji's *Topology*.

> 1. Let $Y$ be Hausdorff, and let $R$ be the relation: $x\sim y$ if there is no continuous $\varphi\colon Y\to I$ with $\varphi(x)\neq \varphi(y)$.
>    a. Show that $R$ is an equivalence relation in $Y$.
>    b. Show that $Y/R$ is completely regular.

So we have, where $I^Y$ are the continuous functions from $Y$ to $I:=[0,1]$,
$$R=\big\{(a,b)\subseteq Y^2\mid \{\varphi\in I^Y\mid \varphi(a)\neq\varphi(b)\}=\emptyset\big\}.$$
a. Is trivial.
b.
*My attempt*: Let $[p]\in Y/R$ and $A\subseteq Y/R$ closed with $[p]\notin A$. This implies $\forall [q]\in A,\; q\nsim p$. For each $[q]\in A$, let $\varphi_{[q]}\in I^Y$ be such that $\varphi_{[q]}(p)\neq \varphi_{[q]}(q)$ (WLOG, $1=\varphi_{[q]}(p)\neq \varphi_{[q]}(q)=0$). Note that, $\forall [q]\in A$, if $x\sim y$, then $\varphi_{[q]}(x)=\varphi_{[q]}(y)$ (since $\varphi_{[q]}\in I^Y$). That is, $\varphi_{[q]}\circ p^{-1}$ is single valued (where $p\colon Y\to Y/R$ is defined by $y\mapsto [y]$ is the identification map) and therefore continuous.

Let $\phi_{[q]}=\varphi_{[q]}\circ p^{-1}$, then
$$\begin{align}\inf_{[q]\in A}\phi_{[q]}\colon Y/R&\to I\\ [y]&\mapsto \inf\{\varphi_{[q]}(y)\mid [q]\in A\}\end{align}$$
is an *upper semi* continuous map with $\inf_{[q]\in A}\phi_{[q]}([p])=1$ and $\forall [q']\in A,\; \inf_{[q]\in A}\phi_{[q]}([q'])=0$. This is as close as I could get (note that I didn't use the fact that $A\subseteq Y/R$ was closed and that Y was Hausdorff).

*The question:* I'm looking for any *hints* (or solutions at this point) to the problem. It's not necessary to continue or do something related to my attempt, I'm stuck and looking for *any* way of prooving it.

Comment: There are completely Hausdorff spaces which are not even regular, so this cannot be true. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn_and_completely_Hausdorff_spaces

Comment: @DavidHartley , the problem consists on proving  $Y/R$ is completely regular, not $Y$.

Comment: For a completely Hausdorff space $Y$, $Y/R$ "is" $Y$. (I've just found a copy of Dugundji online but none of the problems in section 7, Chapter VII is anything like the one you quote!)

Comment: @DavidHartley , can't believe I missed that! Thanks for your comment. In regards to your claim that the problem isn't in the book, I re-wrote the problem so that it is exactly as it appears in my copy of the book (page 159). I found a version on the internet and it seems that the problem was replaced by another one (perhaps on a later edition) suggesting, maybe, a mistake on Dugundji's part. He be trolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David Hartley points out is his comment, thanks by the way, if $Y$ is completely Hausdorff, then $Y\cong Y/R$. Being the case that there exist completely Hausdorff spaces which are not completely regular, the theorem suggested by the problem is *false*.

In my edition of the book (1966), problem 1 of section 7 on chapter VII (p. 159) corresponds to the one shown in the my question. In later versions (such as the twelfth printing, 1978) another problem is proposed instead:

> 1. Let $Y$ be a $T_0$ space satisfying the condition: each $y\in Y$ and closed $A$ not containing $y$ have disjoint nbds. Prove: $Y$ is a regular (Hausdorff) space.

This suggests that a mistake was made in older copies of the book: Dugundji be trolling.

It's easy to adapt my attempted proof to show that $Y/R$ is always completely Hausdorff, $\phi_{[q]}$ being the separating map.